# pymongo find strings in value

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am making a python script that consumes data from MongoDB, the problem is that the data that I must find is within a single value, the fields I need are two identifiers and the date it was generated, I attach an example.
what is the best way to find those two values ​​within a single query? Currently I can find a field, but I don't know how I can search for more than one

```
raw_data.find( {"data": { "$regex": "867162029761533" } }
```

this value "**867162029761533**" is the id, I need to filter by message type for example: "**+RESP:GTINF**" and by date "**20210327193948**"

value example inside mongo database

```
_id:606208d19a159f863be69f3e
source:GPS
data:+BUFF:GTINF,278615,867162029761533,,11,89560100001014459360,24,0,1,12283,0000,4.26,0,1,0,1,20210327193948,1,0,0,00,00,+0000,0,20210327193949,937B$
received_at:2021-03-29T17:05:21.450+00:00
```

all the fields that I am looking for are inside "data"

thanks for help

Comment: Is the value of `data` key a string or a sub-document? Please provide sample input and expected output for query

Comment: data:+BUFF:GTINF,278615,867162029761533,,11,89560100001014459360,24,0,1,12283,0000,4.26,0,1,0,1,20210327193948,1,0,0,00,00,+0000,0,20210327193949,937B$
in this field I have to look up the values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine all the different regex queries in a `$and` field.

Sample Data:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60cacbe8b7468e69c11e52e1"),
    "data" : "_id:606208d19a159f863be69f3e\n        source:GPS\n        data:+BUFF:GTINF,278615,867162029761533,,11,89560100001014459360,24,0,1,12283,0000,4.26,0,1,0,1,20210327193948,1,0,0,00,00,+0000,0,20210327193949,937B$\n        received_at:2021-03-29T17:05:21.450+00:00"
}
```

```
raw_data.find_one({
    "$and": [
        {"data": {"$regex": "606208d19a159"}},
        {"data": {"$regex": "\+BUFF:GTINF"}},  # Prefix special character `+` with escape sequence `\`
        {"data": {"$regex": "20210327193948"}},
    ],
})
```

> Note: Use escape sequence for regex `\` (backslash) wherever you will be using Regex special characters. Like the `\+` in place of `+` in `+BUFF:GTINF` regex search